# How to delete frozen values from a table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-delete, having

hi I HAVE A TABLE LIKE

```
DATE       VALUE            NAME
23MAY       156            CONSUMPTION_1
24MAY       122            CONSUMPTION_1
25MAY       122            COMSUMPTION_1
26MAY       122            CONSUMPTION_1
11APR       177            CONSUMPTION_2
12APR       199            CONSUMPTION_2
13APR       199            CONSUMPTION_2
14APR       199            CONSUMPTION_2
19SEP       318            CONSUMPTION_3
20SEP       282            CONSUMPTION_3
21SEP       183            CONSUMPTION_3
```

nOW HOW TO DELETE THE FROZEN VALUE'S  FOR ALL ROWS
i.e

```
DATE       VALUE            NAME
23MAY       156            CONSUMPTION_1
11APR       177            CONSUMPTION_2
19SEP       318            CONSUMPTION_3
20SEP       282            CONSUMPTION_3
21SEP       183            CONSUMPTION_3
```

tHANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Is there a problem with the caps lock key or do you like shouting?

Comment: What is a "frozen" value?

Comment: Wait is the second table the records you want to _keep_ or the records you want to _delete_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY value 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```